# Modifying list inside function

Tags: python, list

I have question related to list modification inside function. When I replacing elements inside the function in fallowing way: `list_a[0] = 'a'` everything works as expected and after function is finished first element of the `list_a` is `'a'`. But when I want to replace all elements from `list_a` with all element from `list_b`, after function is finished `list_a` is unchanged.

```
def change_list(list_a, list_b):
    print("Type: " + str(type(list_a)) + " ID: " + str(id(list_a)))
    print("Type: " + str(type(list_b)) + " ID: " + str(id(list_b)))
    list_a = list_b
    print("Type: " + str(type(list_a)) + " ID: " + str(id(list_a)))
    print("Type: " + str(type(list_b)) + " ID: " + str(id(list_b)))


list_a = ['a','a','a']
list_b = ['x','x','x']

print(list_a)
print("Type: " + str(type(list_a)) + " ID: " + str(id(list_a)))
print(list_b)
print("Type: " + str(type(list_b)) + " ID: " + str(id(list_b)))
print("\n\n\n\n")


change_list(list_a, list_b)
print(list_a)
print("Type: " + str(type(list_a)) + " ID: " + str(id(list_a)))
print("Type: " + str(type(list_b)) + " ID: " + str(id(list_b)))
```

Why after function `change_list()` is finished `list_a` ID is not pointing the same address as `list_b` ID? while inside function both are the same…

Comment: locals/globals are in effect here

Comment: ``list_a = list_b`` replaces ``list_a``, not *all elements of* ``list_a``. That would be ``list_a[:] = list_b``.

Comment: `list_a = ...` and `list_a[0] = ...` are two very different things. The former creates a local variable, the latter invokes a method through a global variable (`list_a.__setattr__(0, ...)`).

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Python passes all arguments by passing object references, not names or references to names.  There is NO relationship between the name `list_a` in your function and the global name `list_a`.  Think about it this way:

```
def change_list( a, b ):
    a = b

c = 3
d = 7
change_list(c,d)
```

After this code runs, `c` will still be 3.  The function gets two parameters: the integer 3, and the integer 7.  Those objects have NO CONNECTION to the names outside the function.  Within the function `change_list`, `a` starts out bound to the integer 3.  After the first line, `a` becomes bound to the integer 7.  When the function ends, those names go away.  Nothing has changed outside the function.

Your code is exactly the same,  Your `change_list` receives two objects: a list containing `['a','a','a]` and a list containing `['x','x','x']`.  The function knows absolutely nothing about what names those lists might be bound to outside the function.  Inside the function, you change the local name `list_a` to be bound to the list `['x','x','x']`.  Then the function ends and those names evaporate.  Nothing has changed outside the function.

Now, consider making the following change:

```
def change_list( list_a, list_b ):
    list_a.extend(list_b)
```

Here, we are actually changing the list OBJECT that `list_a` is bound to.  If you run that code, you'll see that the global `list_a` has also been changed.  This is not because the names happen to be the same, but because we have changed the object that both names were bound to.

Comment: [Call by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-by-reference#Call_by_reference) actually *does* allow this kind of modification, and languages like Perl and C++ that have true "call by reference" let you directly assign to the variable. Python's calling semantics are not call by reference.

Comment: Yes, Python's calling convention is more like "call by value," where the values are references to objects.  Overloaded terms.  I'll change the wording.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
list_a = list_b
```

causes the local variable `list_a` to point at the list that `list_b` points to, but it does not modify the actual list object that `list_a` previously pointed to.

Since lists are mutable, you *can* modify the actual `list_a` value by doing a slice assignment, which will modify the list itself rather than reassigning the variable:

```
list_a[:] = list_b
```

or by using methods like `clear` and `extend`:

```
list_a.clear()
list_a.extend(list_b)
```

Note that this is not possible with immutable objects, like tuples.  (You *can* reassign variables that point to immutable values in the caller's scope by using the `global` keyword, but this is generally considered Bad and you should not do it, since it may lead to surprising behavior that the caller will not appreciate.)